# Como criar uma cópia de um objeto em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos, referência

Tenho um objeto chamado `cachorro` e gostaria de criar e armazenar uma cópia desse objeto.

Como objetos, vetores, funções e expressões regulares são considerados objetos não consigo fazer uma cópia apenas atribuindo esse objeto a uma outra variável (ex.: `var cachorro2 = cachorro;`), pois por serem objetos apenas uma referência é passada para a outra variável.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum jeito de fazer um cópia de um objeto, seja lá qual for o seu tipo (objetos, vetores, funções ou expressões regulares)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Copiar um objeto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) muitas vezes não é uma tarefa simples; existem diferentes técnicas com seus respectivos *prós* e *contras*.

É especialmente díficil oferecer uma solução completa em JavaScript. Algumas têm problemas de performance. Outras não funcionam para tipos específicos, como [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Suportar [referência circular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference#In_computer_programming) é trabalhoso. E quase todas esbarram no problema do [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) (muito bem explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/1316620)).

## Clone ou cópia?

Uma confusão comum é diferenciar os termos clone e cópia. Em alguns cenários os dois termos são utilizados indistintamente, se referindo ambos a cópia de um objeto. Em outros, *clone* toma um sentido próprio, significa copiar apenas a estrutura do objeto (no caso, o *protótipo*).

Fica só a ressalva; não aprofundarei a dicussão e utilizarei o termo mais correto, *cópia*.

## *Shallow copy* vs *deep copy*

É importante diferenciar os dois tipos de cópias mais comuns: *shallow* e *deep*.

Uma cópia *shallow* (superficial) realiza uma cópia do objeto original, mas as propriedades do objeto original ainda dividem referência com as do objeto cópia. Entenda como o objeto "pai" é copiado mas divide seus "filhos".

Já a cópia *deep* (profunda) realiza também a cópia das propriedades; a cópia do objeto pai possui seus próprios filhos (que também são cópias).

Os exemplos que seguem são de *deep copy*, que é o normalmente desejado.

## [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) & [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var copia = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
```

O maior problema desse método é que as funções do objeto original não estariam presentes no objeto copiado.

Este é o método que todo mundo acaba utilizando quando a cópia não precisa levar em consideração as várias outras complexidades deixadas para trás.

Cuidado com referências circulares pois este método não as suporta (*"TypeError: cyclic object value"*).

## [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) & [toSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource)

```
var copia = eval(original.toSource());
```

Essa é uma das piores soluções, como sempre, [*eval is evil*](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21), além do método *toSource* não ser padrão. Fica apenas como curiosidade; não recomendo.

## Método do [*Brian Huisman*](http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165)

```
function copiarObj(original) {
  var copia = (original instanceof Array) ? [] : {}; // verificando se é um array ou um objeto 'comum' e instanciando a cópia
  for (i in original) { // iterando cada propriedade do objeto original
    if (original[i] && typeof original[i] == 'object') copia[i] = copiarObj(original[i]); // se for um objeto realiza cópia desse objeto (note a recursividade aqui)
    else copia[i] = original[i]; // se não simplesmente copia o valor
  }
  return copia; // retorna a cópia
};
```

Encurtei *levemente* o método original para facilitar a didática.

Existem alguns pequenos problemas, como por exemplo não funcionar para objetos do tipo *Date*, mas no geral ele utiliza um simples loop *for..in* e acaba sendo bem simples. O segredo para que não seja uma cópia *shallow* é a recursividade feita.

Tome cuidado novamente com referências circulares, pois note que ela não é tratada no loop (gerando um loop infinito).

## [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

```
var copia = $.extend(true, {}, original);
```

Resolvi dedicar uma parte exclusivamente para jQuery, que, apesar de ser uma biblioteca e não estará disponível em todos cenários, é amplamente utilizada.

O primeiro paramêtro (*true*) é para que o jQuery faça uma *deep copy*; o segundo (*{ }*) é o objeto de destino, no nosso caso um novo objeto (que é retornado pela função).

## Soluções mais complexas

Como disse, copiar um objeto no JavaScript de forma correta não é uma tarefa fácil. Procurei oferecer apenas exemplos mais comuns e simples, já que a pergunta não aparenta ser para casos complexos.

Segue alguns links de soluções que tentam ser mais completas: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/9023088#9023088), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/11462081#11462081), [[3]](https://web.archive.org/web/20090112172629/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/ScriptingAutomation/Conceptual/JSCodingGuide/OOJavaScript/OOJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006539-SW3), [[4]](https://gist.github.com/NV/1396086).

## Utilize seu framework

Se você utiliza um framework de grande porte, assim como jQuery, pode ser que ele lhe ofereça tal função, como o [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) ou o [MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Object#Object%3aObject-clone).

Se você está utilizando Node.js existe o módulo *clone* ([npm](https://npmjs.org/package/clone), [github](https://github.com/pvorb/node-clone)).

Comment: `JSON.stringify` lança uma exceção se o objeto tem referencia circular.

Comment: Boa observação, adicionarei à resposta.

Comment: Método de Brian Huisman causa um loop infinito em referencia circular, teste: http://jsfiddle.net/gB55W/

Comment: Dependendo da situação Object.assign pode resolver o problema, mas ele copia apenas propriedades enumeráveis e próprias de um objeto de origem para um objeto destino. Isso pode fazê-lo impróprio para combinar novas propriedades com um prototype se os objetos de origem contiverem getters. Para copiar definições de propriedades, incluindo sua enumerabilidade, para prototypes Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() e Object.defineProperty() devem ser utilizadas no lugar.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 13):

Copiar um objecto (com todos os seus atributos e métodos/funções) não é uma tarefa de resposta unica.

No caso de objectos mais complexos recomendo a utilização de uma biblioteca como o [**Mootools**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Object#Object:Object-clone) que tem uma função/método específico para isto: `var clone = Object.clone(obj);`

Aqui fica um exemplo para copiar um objecto simples com javascript:

Objecto:

```
var obj = {
    ano: 2013,
    param2: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']
};
```

Uma função que percorre as suas propriedades e faz uma cópia para um objecto temporário

```
function copiarObjecto(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }
    var temp = obj.constructor();
    for (var key in obj) {
        temp[key] = copiarObjecto(obj[key]);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Atribuir a resposta da função quando se passa um objecto como parametro

```
var objCopia = copiarObjecto(obj);
```

Exemplo:

```js
var obj = {
    ano: 2013,
    param2: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']
};

function copiarObjecto(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }
    var temp = obj.constructor();
    for (var key in obj) {
        temp[key] = copiarObjecto(obj[key]);
    }
    return temp;
}
var objCopia = copiarObjecto(obj);
objCopia.ano = 2014;

console.log(obj);
console.log(objCopia);
```

Comment: Boa resposta, simples e concisa, utilizando JavaScript puro! Só é preciso ter cuidado com objetos que contenham ciclos (i.e. referências pra si próprios). Veja [uma solução alternativa](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/857/como-criar-uma-copia-de-um-objeto-em-javascript/879#879) para esses casos.

Comment: `var temp = obj.constructor();` pode causar problemas se o construtor depender da passagem de parâmetros (e não faltou um `new`?). Talvez seja mais seguro algo como `function F(){}; F.prototype = Object.create(obj); var temp = new F();` para garantir a herança - se o objetivo era esse.

Answer (score 9):

A maneira mais "segura" (i.e. menos sujeita a erros) de se clonar um objeto é utilizando uma biblioteca/framework já existente que suporte essa função, uma vez que clonar em teoria é simples (ver resposta do @Sergio, por exemplo) mas na prática existem detalhes e *edge cases* (casos incomuns) que podem trazer um resultado incorreto e/ou fazer a operação falhar.

Um exemplo é o de um objeto com ciclos (i.e. contendo uma referência pra si próprio):

```
var obj = { x:42 };
obj.y = [obj];
```

A maioria das bibliotecas populares não dão suporte à clonagem desses objetos:

```
// Mootools
console.log(Object.clone(obj)); // Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

// jQuery
console.log($.extend(true, {}, obj)); // Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 

// Underscore.js (Não dá suporte a cópias profundas)
console.log(_.clone(obj).y[0] === obj); // true
```

Nesse caso, uma solução seria usar o utilitário [`cycle.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) da biblioteca JSON-js:

```
var clone = JSON.decycle(obj); // Remove os ciclos
clone = $.extend(true, {}, clone); // Faz a clonagem de fato (pelo método de sua escolha)
clone = JSON.retrocycle(clone); // Refaz os ciclos

console.log(clone === clone.y[0]); // true
```

Comment: Interessante que na minha reprodução do `extend` parece funcionar direitinho e não da o problema de `Maximum call stack`. Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/2Q4Xd/

Comment: @BrunoLM Experimenta `console.log(copia === copia.y[0]); // false` e `console.log(original === copia.y[0]); // true`. Não analisei seu código a fundo pra saber onde é o problema, mas o fato é que ele nao está realmente fazendo uma cópia profunda (uma vez que `copia` contém uma referência para `original`).

Answer (score 8):

Creio que o caminho mais moderno (que funciona em todos navegadores modernos) seria usar `Object.assign()` que pode tornar tudo mais simples e eficiente, ao invés de usar loops ou `JSON.parse()` e muito menos `jQuery` ou qualquer lib externa, um exemplo bem simples:

```js
var original = {
    "foo": "bar"
};

var copia = Object.assign({}, original);
copia.foo = "Olá, Stack Overflow";

//O original não é afetado, pois não é mais uma referencia
console.log("original:", original);

//Exibe o copia
console.log("copia:", copia);
```

Se tentar setar diretamente, ocorre de referenciar, o que vai afetar o original:

```js
var original = {
    "foo": "bar"
};

var copia = original;
copia.foo = "Olá, Stack Overflow";

//O original não é afetado, pois não é mais uma referencia
console.log("original:", original);

//Exibe o copia
console.log("copia:", copia);
```

---

### Compatibilidade

Conforme o MDN, os navegadores suportados são:

- Chrome 45+
- Edge
- Firefox 34
- Safari 9

Todavia existe um **"Polyfill"** para navegadores antigos sugerido pela propria MDN que permite usar em navegadores um pouco mais antigos:

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  // Must be writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true
  Object.defineProperty(Object, "assign", {
    value: function assign(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
      'use strict';
      if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);

      for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[index];

        if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
          for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
            // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
              to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Eu acredito que você possa fazer assim, caso esteja utilizando **jQuery**:

```js
var cachorro2 = $.extend(true, {}, cachorro);
```

ou então com **Underscore**:

```js
var cachorro2 = _.clone(cachorro);
```

Alterações posteriores a `cachorro2` não alterarão mais o objeto `cachorro` e vice-versa.

---

Infelizmente estas soluções não funcionam com **RegEx**, **Data**, etc... Portanto, o método mais elegante de fazer isto é criando uma função como esta chamada `extend`:

```js
function extend(from, to) {
  if (from == null || typeof from != "object") return from;
  if (from.constructor != Object && from.constructor != Array) return from;
  if (from.constructor == Date || from.constructor == RegExp || from.constructor == Function ||
      from.constructor == String || from.constructor == Number || from.constructor == Boolean)
      return new from.constructor(from);

  to = to || new from.constructor();

  for (var name in from) {
    to[name] = typeof to[name] == "undefined" ? extend(from[name], null) : to[name];
  }

  return to;
}
```

E você pode utiliza-la assim:

```
var cachorro2 = extend(cachorro);
```

Veja o [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/caio/c4ygB/).

Comment: Não conheço underscore e lodash, mas se não me engano li que o clone do underscore não é _deep copy_, já no lodash tem isso. Saberia confirmar?

Comment: @BrunoLM Sim, diferente do Underscore, o Lodash tem o `cloneDeep` além do `clone`. http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Answer (score 3):

Uma cópia isolada do método `extend` do jQuery seria da seguinte maneira:

Primeiramente é necessário uma função para ver se o objeto deve ser clonado ou não

```
// para evitar loops infinitos o jQuery clona apenas objetos simples
// objetos complexos ele mantem a referencia

// este método verifica se um objeto é simples ou se é uma instancia
function isPlainObject(obj)
{
    if (typeof (obj) !== "object" || obj.nodeType || (obj instanceof Window))
        return false;

    try
    {
        if (obj.constructor &&
            !({}).hasOwnProperty.call(obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf"))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

E a função para clonar:

```
function extend(deep, target, source)
{
    var copy, original, clone;
    for (var attr in source)
    {
        copy = target[attr];
        original = source[attr];

        if (target === original)
            continue;

        // se for uma cópia profunda e o objeto for simples
        if (deep && original && isPlainObject(original))
        {
            // obtem um objeto simples vazio para ser estendido

            if (original instanceof Array)
            {
                clone = copy && (copy instanceof Array) ? copy : [];
            }
            else
            {
                clone = copy ? copy : {};
            }

            // recursivamente estende o objeto interno 
            target[attr] = extend(deep, clone, original);
        }
        else if (original !== undefined)
        {
            // copia o valor para o objeto de destino
            // caso o objeto seja uma referencia o valor não é clonado
            target[attr] = original;
        }
    }

    // retorna o objeto estendido
    return target;
}
```

Para testar

```
function Pessoa(params)
{
    this.id = params['id'];
    this.nome = params['nome'];
    this.pai = null;
    this.toString = function () { return this.nome };
}

var luke = new Pessoa({ id: 1, nome: 'Luke' });
var vader = new Pessoa({ id: 2, nome: 'Darth' });
luke.pai = vader;
vader.pai = luke; // haha

var copia = extend(true, {}, luke);
luke.nome = "Luke Skywalker";

console.log(luke.nome);  // Luke Skywalker
console.log(copia.nome); // Luke
```

Criei um [exemplo para demonstrar o funcionamento no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Mdp7/1/).

Nota: Fiz algumas modificações e não garanto compatibilidade com browsers antigos.

Answer (score -1):

Uma alternativa para para criar um Objeto cuja seu protótipo herda outro Objeto é a função desenvolvida por *Douglas Crockford*:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```

A referência se encontra [aqui](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html).

Comment: Isso não está copiando o objeto. Apenas criando um _novo_ objeto cujo `[[Prototype]]` é o objeto que se quer copiar. Como as referências serão mantidas, a cópia, de fato, _não_ ocorreu. Fora que o _polyfill_ está incorreto, uma vez que [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) aceita dois argumentos.

Answer (score -1):

Atualmente existem duas formas nativas bem simples de copiar um objeto.
você pode copiar utilizando o operador spread (...).

```js
const obj = {propriedade1: 'a', propriedade2: 'b', metodo: function(){...}}
const obj_copy = {...obj}
```

O spread consegue copiar Arrays, basta substituir as chaves por colchetes:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array_copy = [...array];
```

Porém, ao utilizar o spread, **os atributos de suas propriedades não serão copiados,** eles serão todos defaults.

Se quiser copiar um objeto **exatamente igual, inclusive os atributos de suas propriedades,** basta utilizar esse método que desenvolvi:

```js
    function copy(object, copy) {
    const names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object)
    names.map( ell => {
        if(ell in copy) return;
        let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, ell)
        Object.defineProperty(copy, ell, descriptor)
        })    
    }
```

Aqui demonstro como utilizar o método

```js
const obj = Object.defineProperties({}, {
    name: {value: 'diego', writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true},
    greeting: {value: function() {return this.name}, enumerable: true}
})

let obj2 = {}
copy(obj, obj2)
```

Criei uma função estática chamado 'copy' que pode ser utilizada para copiar objetos normais (que não são arrays), para copiar um array basta utilizar o spread normal

Para utilizá-lo basta declarar um objeto vazio, chamar a função copy, passar o objeto a ser copiado como primeiro parâmetro e o objeto vazio como segundo parâmetro.

Comment: @AugustoVasques inclusvse esse capítulo que citou nem existe no livro
"9.8.2 Defining Immutable Classes"

talvez exista em versões mais antigas e ultrapassadas dele...

Comment: @AugustoVasqueseu adicionei o método no protótipo como exemplo, mas se quiser colocar esse método num objeto novo, com um objeto protótipo novinho em folha, é escolha dele, minha solução vai funcionar da mesma forma...

Comment: @AugustoVasques se eu tirar o método do protótipo e criar um método novinho você desnegativa minha resposta?

Comment: @AugustoVasques vou tirar do protótipo então, mas espero uma setinha para cima para compensar.

Comment: @AugustoVasques ao invés de colocar o método do protótipo fiz uma função própria, estática e sem graça para ver se te agrado (apesar se não ver problema algum de inseri-la no protótipo de Object), estou esperando meu upvote, ebaa.

Comment: @AugustoVasques me dá ao menos um voto positivo ai cara, arrumei direitinho ali como você pediu.
e como você mesmo mencionou a solução é boa, vai, faz isso por mim :)

Comment: Conforme o combinado removi o voto e dei o voto positivo. Você pode constatar através dos seus pontos de reputação que subiram ou desse print do meu voto https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUuyY.png o +1 é meu voto(com a seta em amarelo) o outro voto pertence a outro usuário, por isso sua votação está em zero. Vou retirar os comentários relativos a monkey patch.

Comment: Veja o sumário que agora está com 11 pontos aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/276172/diego-breeg?tab=summary e sua variação de reputação aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/276172/diego-breeg?tab=reputation listando o meu voto.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não se preocupe com isto meu caro, relaxa,
ao menos aprendi hoje sobre monkey patching e isso para mim já está ótimo.