# Como clonar um elemento em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, clone

Há possibilidade de obter um clone exato de um determinado elemento HTML? de forma que o clone contenha todas as propriedades exatamente iguais?

Se houver, gostaria de saber como proceder para realizar este clone, e também entender como o mesmo estaria agindo, de que forma ele estaria clonando, ou seja uma teoria mais conceitual abrangendo acerca do clone em si.

Comment: Possível duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/857/como-criar-uma-copia-de-um-objeto-em-javascript/

Comment: Com certeza não é uma duplicata @GabrielSantos. Não vejo nenhum conteúdo relacionado aqui com lá. Preste atenção no contexto e verás que são coisas diferentes.

Comment: Desculpe. Foi um equívoco.

Comment: Magina, @GabrielSantos, está tudo bem. Fique à vontade para cumprir seu papel de sinalizar questões duplicadas :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Respondendo a pergunta:** Sim, há possibilidade de obter um clone, utilizando javascript nativo, que seria, ou não(você jájá vai saber porque) um clone fiel exatamente igual contendo todas as propriedades do elemento clonado.

**Conceito/Explicação:** Os elementos HTML em seu formato como você pode ver, como código HTML entre tags, eles não são só isso. Cada elemento é um `Node`, que está armazenado dentro do `DOM`(Document Object Model) onde lá estariam contidos todas as informações, funções disponíveis para uso, referência, atributos, valores, dentre outros, resumindo, tudo que um elemento é, está armazenado no `DOM`, sem ele não seriamos capazes de acessar as propriedades dos elementos diretamente. Por isso para obter uma cópia idêntica e exata de outro elemento, podemos clonar o `Node` dele, desta forma estaríamos clonando o que ele é.

**Informações/Exemplos/Prática:** Cada `Node` possui uma função nativa do Javascript chamada `cloneNode()`, onde agora eu explico porque eu disse "ou não" logo no início sobre fazer um clone fiel, que seria no caso o parâmetro `deep` da função `cloneNode()`, que é um parâmetro requerido, ou seja, você tem de informa-lo, vamos conhecer esta função:

### cloneNode([deep])

> ## Argumentos
>
> ***deep (`Boolean`) required***
>
> Se verdadeiro(`true`), duplica a sub-árvore do `Node` como se fosse ele mesmo.
>
> Se falso(`false`), apenas copia o nó (e seus atributos, caso ele for um elemento).
>
> ## Descrição
>
> Cria uma cópia(duplicata) deste `Node`, incluindo todos os atributos, e seus respectivos valores, e atributos, inclusive aqueles que não estão definidos porém contém um valor padrão(default) no `DOM`. O `Node` duplicado, não há um Pai(`parent`), ou seja, o `parentNode` é nulo, apenas enquanto você não inclui ele no documento, como por exemplo usando `appendChild`.
>
> Porém, caso o argumento `deep` seja verdadeiro(`true`), logo a sub-arvore do `Node` também será duplicada.
>
> ## Informações Adicionais
>
> Ao clonar uma sub-árvore que está como `readonly`(somente leitura), resultaria em uma sub-arvore que não pode ser modificada.
>
> Os atributos do `Node` do elemento, ao ser clonado, também são copiados, incluindo os atributos padrão(`default`), porém o texto do elemento não é copiado, apenas se o argumento `deep` é verdadeiro(`true`).
>
> ## Atenção, Informação importante sobre Eventos(creditos ao @bfavaretto):
>
> O Clone não irá ter os eventos do elemento clonado, se você o atribuiu como propriedade ou com `addEventListener` (métodos mais recomendados, aliás), o unico modo que funciona clonagem com eventos é quando o evento está `inline` ou seja: `<div onclick=alert('foo')>` por exemplo.
>
> **Caso queira entender melhor, há um exemplo** [Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/9Aja7/2/)
>
> ## Valor de Retorno:
>
> O `Node` duplicado(clonado).

Bom, agora que já conhecemos a função, vamos a prática:

**Testando com `deep clone` (parâmetro deep = true):**

**Obs: Por favor, utilize um elemento que tenha filhos para melhor entendimento.**

```js
var seuNode = document.getElementById('IDdoElementoQueTemFilhos'); //usei getElementById() por opção você pode resgatar a referência do seu node como quiser.
var clone   = seuNode.cloneNode(true); //aqui você terá seu clone armazenado em variável mas ainda não incluido no Documento, sem parentNode.
document.body.appendChild(clone); //você pode dar append onde quiser, utilizei o body.
```

**Testando com apenas clone (parâmetro deep = false):**

```js
var seuNode = document.getElementById('IDdoElementoQueTemFilhos'); //usei getElementById() por opção você pode resgatar a referência do seu node como quiser.
var clone   = seuNode.cloneNode(false); //aqui você terá seu clone armazenado em variável mas ainda não incluido no Documento, sem parentNode.
document.body.appendChild(clone); //você pode dar append onde quiser, utilizei o body.
```

Note que para o exemplo 1, você obteve o clone dele completo, incluindo os filhos que ele tem, ou seja, a sub-árvore dele.

Já para o exemplo 2, você só obteve o clone do isolado elemento, apenas ele, sem obter a cópia dos filhos também(sub-árvore).

Dependendo do seu uso você poderá alternar entre os dois métodos de clonar. Também há outras maneiras até utilizando o `.clone()` do jQuery, porém, eu considero melhor utilizar esta maneira que tem fidelidade do clone de um `Node` e é javascript nativo, não necessitando de plugins externos.

Comment: Visualmente, ótimo, o `cloneNode` resolve. Mas cuidado, porque ele não copia eventos atribuídos aos elementos clonados.

Comment: Tem certeza @bfavaretto ? realizei esse teste agora mesmo e obtive sucesso em clonar com evento também, veja você mesmo http://jsfiddle.net/9Aja7/

Comment: Funciona nesse caso porque você passou o listener inline, como atributo. Se você atribuir como propriedade ou com `addEventListener` (métodos mais recomendados, aliás), o evento não é clonado. http://jsfiddle.net/9Aja7/1/

Comment: Que triste @bfavaretto, isso me desanimou um pouco, mas pelo menos isso é uma informação importante que vou adicionar à resposta.

Comment: Entendo o desânimo... Até porque contornar isso não é tão simples no caso do addEventListener. O jQuery consegue porque abstrai totalmente essa parte de eventos, então mantém uma lista dos eventos de todo mundo.

Answer (score 3):

No jQuery existe o método [jQuery.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) que permite clonar elementos (com ou sem seus respectivos eventos)

Considere o seguinte exemplo

**Estrutura HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="exemplo">Uma div</div>
</div>
```

**Código Javascript**

```
// Evento simples de clique
$('.exemplo').on('click', function() {
    alert('Evento click');
});

// Clona o elemento com classe "exemplo"
var $clone = $('.exemplo').clone();

// Clona o elemento com classe "exemplo" juntamente com seus eventos
var $cloneComEventos = $('.exemplo').clone(true);

// Adiciona os elementos clonados no elemento wrapper
$('.wrapper').append($clone);
$('.wrapper').append($cloneComEventos);
```

O elemento wrapper possuirá um total de 3 elementos, sendo que o primeiro (original) e terceiro (sua cópia) possuirão eventos click

Em prática:
http://jsfiddle.net/wTdg2/