# usando o hook do plugin jquery.cloneya

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou usando o *plugin* do [`jquery.cloneya`](https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya) que é um *plugin* para clonar formulários que já estavam inclusos em um *template* de um painel administrativo que estou usando. Não entendi muito bem como usar o *hook* desse *plugin* para incrementar o *name* de um *input* sempre que ele é clonado.

**Por exemplo:** Clico no sinal de "+" e clono um ou dois campos juntos. Estes dois campos têm seu *name* incrementado desse jeito > "`name='produtos[qtd][2]'`", sendo o índice do primeiro input começava com "`[qtd][0]`".

Perguntei ao desenvolvedor do *plugin* se era possível fazer o clone e incrementar os *names* e ele me respondeu o seguinte:

"Yes, it is. Ideally, due to the nature of cloned form elements, the names should be name[], so that the values can be processed as arrays. If you need to increment name and/or value, you can plug into the custom event - `clone_form_input`.

See: https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya/blob/master/jquery-cloneya.js#L119.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara pra mim. Sua dúvida é como clonar e acrescentear o [qtd][] ??
Como seu codigo está hoje?

Comment: sim, digamos que você possua um formulário, e deseja clonar um `<select>` e um input do tipo text, e toda vez que você criar um clone desses dois elementos, você queira incrementar +1 à o name do input, se eu tenho um input **"produtos[qtd][]"** = produtos=>quantidade=>(array ID do input). ele deveria ficar produtos[qtd][1], produtos[qtd][2]... sempre que um novo clone é criado.

Comment: essa sua pergunta não foi respondida aqui? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9548/como-clonar-um-elemento-com-jquery-e-adicionar-um-novo-name

Comment: não, essa pergunta não é referente à este plugin. na verdade, foi respondida mas sem o uso do plugin, agora preciso usando o plugin.

Comment: Como não? Está lá... Jquery CloneYa

Comment: sim, mas o sujeito respondeu com js puro. essa pergunta se reserva ao plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente a documentação do plugin é bem fraca, dificultando muito a sua utilização.

De qualquer maneira criei um exemplo de como se criar um formulário com Javascript puro. Acho que você vai ter que acabar aceitando essa solução mesmo.

## HTML

```
<button id='botao'>
    Adicione um formulário
</button>

<div id='formulario'>
    <form id='form' action='#'>
        <input type='submit' id='submit'></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

## Javascript

```
var sequencia = 0;

var form = document.getElementById('form');
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');

var cria_formulario = function() {

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'entrada[' + sequencia + ']');
    input.setAttribute('value', 'entrada[' + sequencia + ']');
    sequencia += 1;

    form.removeChild(submit);
    form.appendChild(input);
    form.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    form.appendChild(submit);
};

var botao = document.getElementById('botao');
botao.onclick = function() {
    cria_formulario();
}
```

## JSFiddle

[Veja no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSbWG/).