# Como duplicar uma div ao clicar em uma outra

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma div chamada `contatoFormIncluir`, dentro dela tenho outra div chamada `contatoBtMais`, quero fazer o seguinte; quando eu clicar no `contatoBtMais` ele duplique a div `contatoFormIncluir`. Tem como?

Meu HTML está assim:

```
<div class="contatoFormIncluir">
    <div class="contatoFormInteiro">
        <div class="contatoBGCinza">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="cadastroLinha">
                <div class="cadastroTituloItem">Curso:</div>
                <input id="cursoCursoForm" name="cursoCursoForm" type="text" class="cadastroItemInput" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="cadastroLinha">
                <div class="cadastroTituloItem">Entidade:</div>
                <input id="entidadeForm" name="entidadeForm" type="text" class="cadastroItemInput" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="cadastroLinha">
                <div class="cadastroTituloItem">Carga hor&aacute;ria:</div>
                <input id="cargaForm" name="cargaForm" type="text" class="cadastroItemInput" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="cadastroLinha">
                <div class="cadastroTituloItem">Obs:</div>
                <input id="obsForm" name="obsForm" type="text" class="cadastroItemInput" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contatoBtMais"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

o Jquery está assim:

```
$( "contatoBtMais" ).click(function() {
    $(".contatoFormIncluir").append();
});
```

Sim, o Jquery está errado, não sei como proceder.

Answer (score 2):

Como explicado pelo Paulo Roberto nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4321/como-clonar-um-elemento-em-javascript), você pode utilizar a função [jQuery.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/). Basta navegar corretamente pelos elementos:

```
$('.contatoBtMais').click(function(e){
    var f = $(this).parent().parent(),
        c = f.clone(true,true);
    c.insertAfter(f);
});
```

Acima, a variável `f` é `.contatoFormIncluir` do `.contatoBtMais` que foi clicado, a variável `c` é um clone de `.contatoFormIncluir` copiando inclusive eventos Javascript.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/MDL48/

Answer (score 1):

Deixo mais uma reposta pois acho que usar `.closest()` é mais seguro do que usar *n* vezes `.parent()`, pois no caso de o elemento clicado ser descendente "profundo" do elemento que se quere copiar, o código vai parecer `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()... etc` e isto não é bom.

Assim a minha sugestão para a pergunta é:

```
$( ".contatoBtMais" ).click(function() {
    var original = $(this).closest(".contatoFormIncluir");
    var copia = original.clone(true, true);
    original.after(copia); // ver (*) em baixo
});
```

Note:

- o método [**.clone()**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) aceita 2 argumentos. O primeiro diz "sim ou não" a copiar os event handlers; o segundo faz ou não cópia dos descendentes também. Aqui talvez queira ter `false, true` mas como não tinha certeza de como vai usar o código deixei `true, true`.
- `(*)` esta ultima linha adiciona a nova `copia` a seguir ao elemento `original`. Não tenho a certeza que é aí que quer a cópia, mas é um exemplo. Mais info sobre `.after` [**aqui**](http://api.jquery.com/after/).