# Cópia de objetos do DOM como novo objeto com JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero inserir a cópia de um conteúdo em duas divs
Fiz um clone  e depois queria fazer um append. Sendo que o append move o conteúdo do último insert no DOM.

```js
var copia = $('div#conteudo').children().clone(true);

$('div#vazia1').append(copia);
$('div#vazia2').append(copia);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo">
    <p> meu conteudo </p>
</div>

<div id="vazia1">
    <p> vazia 1 </p>
</div>

<div id="vazia2">
    <p> vazia 2 </p>
</div>
```

O problema me parece ser a questão da cópia. Questão parecida já foi abordada em [Como criar uma cópia de um objeto em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/857/como-criar-uma-c%C3%B3pia-de-um-objeto-em-javascript) mas a resposta ainda continua vaga, quiçá complicada.

Como fazer uma simples cópia e não fazer uma passagem por referência?
Mostro o problema em https://jsfiddle.net/bnascimento/j0xbs6qt/2/

Quero fazer uma cópia de elementos do DOM e, modificar o original sem que a cópia receba as alterações. Quero que essa cópia seja um novo elemento independente do primeiro. Isso é possível?

Comment: Verifiquei que:  $('div#vazia1').append(copia.clone(true); Funciona! Mas, não sei explicar o porquê.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas parece que você só fez uma cópia e queria colocar em dois lugares. Isso não funciona mesmo já que é o mesmo objeto e não pode estar em dois lugares ao mesmo tempo. Do jeito que você vez agora você criou um novo clone, então resolve.

Comment: Eu consigo fazer uma cópia de um objeto com referências diferentes? Do jeito que fiz não dá o resultado apropriado.  Eu preciso inserir um novo objeto que é cópia de outro. Pode ver o erro em https://jsfiddle.net/bnascimento/j0xbs6qt/1/

Comment: Acho que realmente não entendi. Seria interessante se você editasse a pergunta colocando, além dos fiddles, a saída esperada.

Comment: @Pablo fiz a alteração na pergunta. Espero que esteja mais clara.

Comment: Você clona uma única vez, e coloca o memos clone em dois lugares diferentes (em `div#vazia1` e `div#vazia2`). Você precisa adicionar a cada uma dessas div's clones diferentes.

Comment: Ok @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira pode mostrar um exemplo de clonar (copiar) um objeto e fazer com que eles sejam diferentes? A ideia é não criar novos elementos, mas copiar o que já existe e replicar em outros lugares como um novo elemento.