# Como alterar uma variável sem alterar a outra?

Tags: javascript

Quando copio uma variável, se altero a cópia, altero consequentemente a primeira variável. Como mudar o valor da segunda sem afetar a primeira ?

```js
var cont = [10, 1, 3];

alert(cont.length + "\n");

var tmp_cont = cont;
tmp_cont.pop();

alert(cont.length + " : " + tmp_cont.length + "\n");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `slice`, faz uma cópia do vetor para você, gerando 2 vetores independentes.

```
var vector1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var vector2 = vector1.slice();

vector2.pop();
alert(""+vector1.length+" : "+vector2.length);
```

Comment: Funciona. Obrigado !

Comment: Estamos aqui pra isso mesmo!

Answer (score 3):

Em JavaScript alguns *tipos* têm esse comportamento e variáveis que recebam o *tipo* são meras referências ao *tipo* inicial e não cópias independentes.

Isso é o caso de objetos, arrays e funções. Mas não é o caso de numeros, strings e booleanos. O problema que descreves na pergunta não acontece com estes, também chamados *tipos primitivos*.

Para resolver o problema, tens diferentes opções dependendo do *tipo* com que estás a lidar. Para arrays já tens uma alternativa [noutra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116670/129), podes também usar outras variantes que funcionam também para objetos. Para objetos complexos podes fazer com ideias [destas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/857/129), a maneira mais simples (para objetos ou arrays só com Primitivos) é

```
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Para copiar funções a maneira mais simples é usar `new`, assim ficas com uma instância diferente, que partilha o *prototype*.