# Como funciona a cópia de objetos?

Tags: javascript, objetos

```
var a = {a: 1, b: 2};
var b = a;

b.a = 3;
```

No código acima, *b.a* passa a valer 3, e *a.a* também passa a valer 3.

```
var a = {a: 1, b: 2};

function b(objeto) {
    objeto.a = 3;
}

b(a);
```

No código acima, o valor de *a.a* continua sendo 1, pois não estou editando o objeto a, e sim uma cópia dele (me corrijam se eu estiver errado).

Agora eis a dúvida:

```
var a = {a: 1, b: 2};

function copy(objeto) {
    return objeto;
}

var b = copy(a);

b.a = 3;
```

No código acima, *a.a* também vale 3. Por que?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o seu resultado do segundo trecho de código:  `Exception: TypeError: objeto is undefined`.

Comment: Código corrigido, Pablo.

Comment: parece que ele esta simplesmente linkando o objeto a com o b vou colocar uma forma que encontrei para fazer a clonagem

Comment: Agora `a.a` continua sendo 3.

Comment: O mais proximo  e simples para clonagem de um objeto seria desta forma: var copiedObject = jQuery.extend({}, originalObject)

Comment: Se sua intenção é obter um meio de fazer uma cópia completa sempre, dê uma olhada nessa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/881/26404

Comment: O segundo código terá o membro `a` mudado para 3. O objeto é passado por referência. Você está alterando o objeto mesmo e não uma cópia.

Comment: Meu objetivo não é fazer uma cópia. Quero entender por que isso ocorre. Qual a diferença do segundo código e do terceiro código? Por que um modifica o objeto e outro não?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua segunda suposição está errada, veja:

```js
var a = {a: 1, b: 2};

function b(objeto) {
    objeto.a = 3;
}

b(a);

document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
```

`a.a` passa a valer `3` quando você faz `objeto.a = 3;`, então o segundo código tem resultado idêntico ao terceiro.

O ponto principal que você precisa entender é que objetos em JS são sempre passados por referência, então alterar atributos deles na função para a qual foram passados irá sempre resultar no objeto original sendo alterado. Dê uma lida [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15260/21328) para entender bem como funciona.

Comment: Bruno, isso só acontece com objetos ou variáveis também são passadas como referência?

Comment: @André apenas objetos e arrays (arrays são mais ou menos objetos em js, é meio confuso), valores são copiados. Leia o post que linkei, lá detalha bem isso.

Comment: @André _Primitivos_ não são passados por referência. BrunoBR: `+1`

Comment: Quando você diz que são passados por referência, você está falando de atribuição ou passagem por parâmetro? Porque as passagens por parâmetros são todas por valor, não por referência.

Comment: A passagem de objetos por parâmetro gera uma uma cópia da referência, que é o que possibilita você alterar os valores do objeto original e que contudo não permite que você altere a referência do objeto original. Como já comentei antes [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2695/como-funcionam-os-tipos-valor-e-tipos-refer%C3%AAncia-em-javascript/15260#15260) já detalha bem o funcionamento.

Comment: Sim, só que uma atribuição também gera uma cópia da referência. Não está errado, só que falar assim parece que uma passagem de parâmetro é diferente de uma atribuição, o que no JS não é (referente ao valor que é passado).

Answer (score 4):

O JS trabalha os objetos como referência. Ou seja, a variável do objeto é só o endereço de memória de onde estão os dados.

O tipo objeto (que [no fundo é um *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122341/101)) é o único tipo considerado um tipo por referência. Os demais tipos de dados do JS são por valor, portanto a variável guarda o valor propriamente dito e não um endereço onde o valor está.

#### Exemplo 1

Então se você copia o valor dessa variável para outra (**endereço do objeto**), apenas terá duas variáveis apontando para o mesmo objeto, portanto qualquer alteração neste objeto refletirá nas duas variáveis.

#### Exemplo 2

Um parâmetro é apenas uma variável que recebe um valor. Se este valor é um **endereço de um objeto**, é uma cópia desse valor, mas não do objeto. No fundo ocorre a mesma coisa que o caso anterior.

#### Exemplo 3

Aqui a função recebe o **endereço do objeto** e em seguida retorna ele para quem chamou. Este resultado é guardado em uma variável. No fundo ocorreu a mesma coisa aqui também.

```js
var a = {a: 1, b: 2};

var b = a;
b.a = 3; 
document.body.innerHTML += a.a; //imprime 3

function change(objeto) {
    objeto.a = 3;
}

change(a);
document.body.innerHTML += a.a; //imprime 3

function copy(objeto) {
    return objeto;
}

var b = copy(a);
b.a = 3;
document.body.innerHTML += a.a; //imprime 3
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/Copy.js).

Answer (score 2):

Objetos passados por referência alteram sempre o original.

No teu segundo exemplo o que acontece é o mesmo que no primeiro:

```
function b(objeto) {
    objeto.a = 3;
    console.log(objeto.a); // 3
}

b(a);
console.log(a.a); // 3
```

a terceira versão do código é basicamente o mesmo que a segunda. O resultado que obtêns é o mesmo com a diferença semântica que a função do terceiro exemplo não tem retorno.

Answer (score 1):

sei que já tem a sua explicação, mas gostaria de mencionar o [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), que serve justamente para mesclar objetos:

```js
var a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var b = Object.assign({}, a);

b.a = 4;

console.log(a, b);
```

Porém depedendo dos browsers que deseja dá suporte, possivelmente você terá de usar o seguinte Polyfill:

```
if (!Object.assign) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(target) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[i];
        if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
          continue;
        }
        nextSource = Object(nextSource);

        var keysArray = Object.keys(Object(nextSource));
        for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
          var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
          var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
          if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    }
  });
}
```