# Clonar funções de forma profunda

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de clonar alguns objetos de forma profunda. Eu já vi essa pergunta:

[Como criar uma cópia de um objeto em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/857/como-criar-uma-c%C3%B3pia-de-um-objeto-em-javascript)

...Porém, nenhuma das respostas oferece uma forma de se clonar uma função de forma profunda. Em outras palavras, se um objeto matriz tiver funções, seus clones terão referências para essa função.

Vou dar um exemplo. Com o seguinte objeto como ponto de partida:

```
var cores = {
    Amarelo: function () {}
}
cores.getAmarelo.prototype.r = 255;
cores.getAmarelo.prototype.g = 255;
cores.getAmarelo.prototype.b = 0;
```

Se eu fizer uma clonagem rasa, o clone terá a mesma função `Amarelo`, por referência... E por isso alterar o protótipo da função em um objeto afetará também seu clone. I.e.:

```
var paletaDaltonica = {};
for (var cor in cores) {
    paletaDaltonica[cor] = cores[cor];
}

paletaDaltonica.Amarelo.prototype.r = 120;
// Isso alterou o protótipo de Amarelo no objeto original também.
```

É possível clonar uma função de forma profunda, de forma que o clone tenha a mesma funcionalidade e protótipo da função original, mas mantendo isoladas as alterações em seus respectivos protótipos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu problema está sendo com **Herança**, primeiro você deve definir o objeto:

```
// Define o objeto
paletaDaltonica[cor] = function() {};
```

Depois você herda o protótipo do objeto original utilizando [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

```
// Herda de: cores[cor]()
paletaDaltonica[cor].prototype = Object.create(cores[cor].prototype);
```

#### Referência

- [Introdução ao JavaScript Orientado a Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
- [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

#### Veja funcionando:

```js
var cores = {
    Amarelo: function () {}
}
cores.Amarelo.prototype.r = 255;
cores.Amarelo.prototype.g = 255;
cores.Amarelo.prototype.b = 0;

var paletaDaltonica = {};
for (var cor in cores) {
  // Define o objeto
  paletaDaltonica[cor] = function() {};
  // Herda de: cores[cor]()
  paletaDaltonica[cor].prototype = Object.create(cores[cor].prototype);
}

paletaDaltonica.Amarelo.prototype.b = 120;
paletaDaltonica.Amarelo.prototype.teste = 'Testando ...'
console.log(cores.Amarelo.prototype, paletaDaltonica.Amarelo.prototype);


var paletaDaltonicaB = {};
// Define o objeto
paletaDaltonicaB.Amarelo = function() {};
// Herda de: paletaDaltonica.Amarelo
paletaDaltonicaB.Amarelo.prototype = Object.create(paletaDaltonica.Amarelo.prototype);
paletaDaltonicaB.Amarelo.prototype.r = 124;
paletaDaltonicaB.Amarelo.prototype.g = 432;
paletaDaltonicaB.Amarelo.prototype.b = 3472;
paletaDaltonicaB.Amarelo.prototype.teste = 'Valor modificado ...'

cores.Amarelo.prototype.b = 200;
console.log(cores.Amarelo.prototype, paletaDaltonica.Amarelo.prototype, paletaDaltonicaB.Amarelo.prototype);
```

Comment: Pequena variação: `paletaDaltonica[cor].prototype = Object.create(cores[cor].prototype);`. O resultado é o mesmo.